# How do I add help text to my jar file that I can access from Windows CMD?

Tags: java, jar

How do I add help to my jar-file?

If I put something like this in Windows CMD
`java -jar myjar.jar` or `help myjar.jar` or `myjar /?`

I want a list in CMD like this

```
usage: myjar
 -sourceFile <arg>   The source pdf
 -destFile <arg>     The destination pdf
```

Comment: I don’t think you can do `help myjar.jar`, but the other two can be accomplished with simple logic in your `main` method.  Have you tried adding code there?

Comment: Yes I can run my code, but don't know how I can add help.

Comment: Have you tried adding code that examines the string array passed to `main`?